# How to create Consumer Group for event hub in Microsoft Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-eventhub

We can Create the Consumer group by calling CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists from the code. But is there a way we can Create it from the Microsoft Azure Portal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the old Azure Portal you can access it via https://manage.windowsazure.com.

Azure Portal -> Service Bus Tab -> myServiceBus -> Event Hub Tab -> myHub

Once inside the Event Hub, there should be a "CONSUMER GROUPS" tab at the top, click on that. Once inside, in the navy blue footer, there should be a "create" button which will let you create a new consumer group. Attached below is a diagram on how to get to this.

[image: UI Diagram]

Comment: Any idea why the "Create" option might be disabled?

Comment: I submitted a response Roshan.

Comment: Same here, in both the old and new portal, the Create option is disabled for me.

Answer (score 4):

Create a consumer group in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com/) by the following steps:

Azure Portal > Event Hubs > Event Hub > Consumer Groups > +Consumer Group

Make sure that you've created a Event Hub within your Event Hubs instance. The **Consumer Groups** tab will be under **"Entities"** of the Event Hub page.

[image]